# What's the official way of logging in with a personal access token using the client4 go driver for mattermost?

Tags: go, mattermost

We're running two mattermost servers.

One we have a python process logging in with https://github.com/Vaelor/python-mattermost-driver using a personal access token with the community Python driver. 
This process has a session that doesn't time out which is one of the benefits of using a personal access token to login.
https://docs.mattermost.com/developer/personal-access-tokens.html .

We log in using a username and password with the client4 go driver and this works however it times out after a while. It appears there is no way of using a personal access token to log in with the official client 4 driver.

The documentation for the Mattermost Client4 code is at
https://godoc.org/github.com/mattermost/platform/model#Client

The source for client4 is at https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-server/blob/master/model/client4.go

The closest thing that looks like it would work is logging in under with a username and password and then setting the authentication token via client.MockSession which failed on testing.

What's the official way of logging in with a personal access token using the client4 go driver for mattermost?

Comment: Judging from the code, simply set the client's `AuthToken` field to the token and `AuthType` to `"Bearer"`. I would assume that `SetOAuthToken` is supposed to do that, but it sets `AuthType` to `"token"`. That's a bug if you ask me.

Comment: That's pretty much what I ended up doing and then made a call to client.GetMe()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is *not* logging in, setting the personal access token and calling client.GetMe.
This became clear after looking through the python driver source code.
The relevant fragment is.

```
    fmt.Println("LoginAsTheBotUser", "Using personal access token")
    client.AuthToken = mattermost_personal_access_token
    client.AuthType = model.HEADER_TOKEN
    if user, resp := client.GetMe(""); resp.Error != nil {
        println("There was a problem logging into the Mattermost server.  Are you sure the access token is valid?")
        PrintError(resp.Error)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(client)
        botUser = user
        result = true
    }
```

Context.

```
/* 
    mattermost_user_email, mattermost_user_password and mattermost_personal_access_token
    are globals set from reading a .env file on startup
    */
func LoginAsTheBotUser() bool {
    fmt.Println("LoginAsTheBotUser")
    fmt.Println("LoginAsTheBotUser", time.Now())
    var result bool = false
    if mattermost_personal_access_token == "" {
        fmt.Println("LoginAsTheBotUser", "Getting access token from login with username and password")
        if user, resp := client.Login(mattermost_user_email, mattermost_user_password); resp.Error != nil {
            println("There was a problem logging into the Mattermost server.  Are you sure ran the setup steps from the README.md?")
            PrintError(resp.Error)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(client)
            botUser = user
            result = true
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println("LoginAsTheBotUser", "Using personal access token")
        client.AuthToken = mattermost_personal_access_token
        client.AuthType = model.HEADER_TOKEN
        if user, resp := client.GetMe(""); resp.Error != nil {
            //if user, resp := client.Login(mattermost_personal_access_token); resp.Error != nil {
            println("There was a problem logging into the Mattermost server.  Are you sure the access token is valid?")
            PrintError(resp.Error)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(client)
            botUser = user
            result = true
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("LoginAsTheBotUser", time.Now())
    fmt.Println("LoginAsTheBotUser")
    return result
}
```